# vscode extension: how to get the range of the current line

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I could use `Range` or `Selection` constructor to get the `Range` or `Selection` of the current line, but I wonder if there is any easier way to achieve the same? What I really want to do is to replace the current line of text with something else. Currently I am using the `activeTextEditor`'s `edit` method. It seems vscode editor apis are quite low level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is about as directly as possible to replace the current line in the current text editor:

```js
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
const selection = editor.selection;

// get the range of the current line, I don't think there is an easier way in the api
const currentLineRange = editor.document.lineAt(selection.active.line).range;

editor.edit(edit => edit.replace(currentLineRange, "my new text"));
```